# Only one check box checked at a time in Delphi

Tags: delphi, checkbox

*Issue*:  I have two checkboxes (only one has to check at a time) and one edit box. For the both the checkboxes when they are checked, value in the edit box has to change to '0' otherwise original value will remain in the edit box. Below are the two onclick events for the two checkboxes. when I write chkFacetoFace.checked := false the respective onclick handler is called and I was unable to achieve the desired result. Can anyone please help me on resolving this issue ?

```
procedure TForm1.chkFacetoFaceClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if chkFacetoFace.Checked then
    begin
      edtConvFee.Text := '0.00';
      chkWaiveOff.Checked := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      edtConvFee.Text := '5.00';
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.chkWaiveOffClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if chkWaiveOff.Checked then
    begin
      edtConvFee.Text := '0.00';
      chkFacetoFace.Checked := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      edtConvFee.Text := '5.00';
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You can temporarily unassign the `OnClick` handlers.

Comment: "I have two checkboxes (only one has to check at a time)". Use `RadioButton` instead

Comment: @ValMarinov IMHO, for RadioButton user expects that one value has to be checked, an completely unchecked RadioGroup would irritate the user.

Comment: yeah I thought of that but user can proceed without selecting any check box. so radio button won't help right ?

Comment: @OP what happens with current code? I suppose that `Edit.Text` gets `5.00`?

Comment: @TLama If we unassign the even handler the checkbox which is  checked cannot be unchecked. I want only one checkbox to be checked at a time

Comment: @RenéHoffmann Yes you are right when the checkbox is checked the value is displayed as 5.00 which is wrong.. it should be 0.00 if we check any of the checkboxes ..only if we uncheck it should become 5.00

Comment: Check box is wrong here. You need a radio group with three options. The extra corresponds to neither check box checked. There's a well known UI idiom here. Check boxes tell the user that they can combine options. Radio buttons tell the user that options are mutually exclusive. Don't confuse the user in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As TLama commented:

   > You can temporarily unassign the OnClick handlers.
2. Value of `EditBox.Text` is set in not intended cases. You should check both Checkboxe's `Checked` states before changing `EditBox.Text`. See this example:

.

```
procedure TForm1.chkWaiveOffClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if chkWaiveOff.Checked then
  begin
    edtConvFee.Text := '0.00';
    chkFacetoFace.Checked := False;
  end
  else if not chkFaceToFace.Checked then // <-- additional check for the respective checkbox
  begin
    edtConvFee.Text := '5.00';
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

@David Heffernan said "Check box is wrong here."

try this:

```
procedure TForm1.chk1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 inherited;
   chk1.OnClick := nil;
   chk2.OnClick := nil;
   chk2.OnClick := nil;
   if TCheckBox(Sender).Name = 'chk1' then
   begin
     chk2.Checked := False;
     chk3.Checked := False;
   end
   else if TCheckBox(Sender).Name = 'chk2' then
   begin
     chk1.Checked := False;
     chk3.Checked := False;
   end
   else if TCheckBox(Sender).Name = 'chk3' then
   begin
     chk1.Checked := False;
     chk2.Checked := False;
   end;
   chk1.OnClick := chk1Click;
   chk2.OnClick := chk1Click;
   chk3.OnClick := chk1Click;
 end;`
```

Comment: Quoting  Only represents exatly what David said... by that I mean that I agree and those are not my words. i should of said : Like @David Heffernan said "Check box is wrong here."

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought you thought the quote meant that it's not possible with check boxes and you're proving otherwise. Sometimes using a few extra words makes a phrase more clear. ;)

Comment: Thank you Marisco